# How can I design this better using OO and SOLID principles?

Tags: oop, solid-principles

I've found lots of similar posts about related questions, this reply by [taylonr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5778939/how-can-i-design-this-better-avoiding-a-switch-statement-with-object-oriented) came close but didn't quite answer my scenario.

Assume I have an interface:

```
public interface IShape
{
    decimal GetArea();
}
```

I then create 3 classes using this interface

```
public class Rectangle : IShape
{
    public decimal GetArea()
    {
        ...
    }
}

public class Triangle : IShape
{
    public decimal GetArea()
    {
        ...
    }
}

public class Circle : IShape
{
    public decimal GetArea()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

I now want to add a `int GetNumberOfSides()` function (or some other function which is only relevant to some of my IShape's).  Obviously this isn't relevant to the Circle class.  If I then had a `List<IShape>` objects and wanted to iterate over call this function on relevant IShapes, how would you using object oriented design principles go about addressing this?

I could add a boolean to my IShape interface `bool HasSides { get; set; }` and run any logic of this, however I would need to cast to a specific class in order to access a `GetNumberOfSides()` function.  I know this isn't right as it doesn't feel right, but I'm not sure how to do this.

I've thought about having another interface `ISidedShape` which inherited from `IShape`, but then back to iterating of my list how would I know which of the shapes had this specific method?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can't a `Circle` simply `return 0;` for the number of sides?  What about other odd shapes, such as a semi-circle?  That would legitimately have 1 "side", as well as 1 "something other than a side, depending on how you define a side".  Maybe "side" isn't the term you're looking for?  With a more apt name for the term, the modeling might make more sense.

Comment: My example may not have been the best.  I was struggling finding a example without using my actual scenario which would require other knowledge.  I get your point about returning 0 but that doesn't feel right either.

Comment: Why doesn't it feel right?  It's perfectly logical.

Comment: `IShape` is a distraction. I suggest that `IShape` is no different from `Object` for the purpose of this question. Ask yourself, _If I had a `List<Object>` and wanted to iterate and call functions on relevant Objects, how would I use object-oriented design principles to address this?_

Comment: @jrahhali, I agree in this example it makes perfect sense.  The example I gave doesn't directly match with my real life scenario.  In my scenario, I have two types, one inherits from the other and provides additional functions which only make sense to have on the second. So implementing them all in one interface doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go the OOP route, you could add an interface, since you can implement as many as you like in most languages:

```
public interface IPolygon
{
    int GetNumberOfSides();
}

public class Rectangle : IShape, IPolygon
{
    public decimal GetArea() { return 0; }
    public int GetNumberOfSides() { return 4; }
}
```

It is true that all polygons are shapes; however, the last several years has taught many OOPers that inheritance can be both powerful and incredibly dangerous, and that generally speaking, a composite relationship is preferred over a hierarchical one when it makes sense to do so.

I feel compelled to say that while this is a good academic exercise, the quintessential "shapes" OOP example often does not translate that well to the "real world" and as such, many programmers find themselves over-complicating what could otherwise be a simple approach. Since everything must be an object, we are coerced to mapping our data onto the object model, which often means that we forcibly fit our data to the paradigm or develop constructs to make things work, instead of simply working with the data.  "Simple" is king, and complexity is the enemy.

Comment: Thanks Josh.  When looping over a `List<IShape>` would you then use `is IPolygon` to determine whether to cast it to a `IPolygon`?

Answer (score 0):

If you're already having `List<IShape>` in some places in your code (so you rely on `IShape` polymorphism), I would say the best solution is to add `GetNumberOfSides()` to `IShape` and implement it as

```
public class Circle : IShape
{
    public decimal GetNumberOfSides()
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

If you are still in the "design" phase and you actually don't have code that is using `List<IShape>` you could implement a second interface `IPolygon` (exactly like @Josh answer).

Either one of the other of these two solutions is suited (depending on how `IShape` is currently used) and an "OOP approach". I can't say which one is better because you didn't show us your real code (and it wouldn't be relevant to make such a decision based on a shape example).

However, the only approach I would discourage is adding an `hasSides` method in `IShape` because your code will soon be cluttered with a lot of `if` every time you will iterate on a `List<IShape>` and therefore will be a nightmare to test and maintain. So please let the polymorphism handle the branching instead of manually branching with `if` on `boolean`.

Comment: Wouldn't you just be replacing `if hasSides` with `if xxx is IPolygon` when looping over over your `List<IShape>`?

Comment: @user1244893 If you design your system in advance with `IPolygon`, an acceptable option (maybe) would be to also have a `List<IPolygon>`. However, you would have two lists to maintain now instead of one. So the first approach (adding `GetNumberOfSides` to `IShape`) seems the most maintainable one to me.

Answer (score 0):

It comes under the LSP and IS principle
If you add the method getSides() to the IShape interface it will violate the LSP when that interface is implemented by Circle as it doesn't have sides.
So you want to create a new IPolygon interface as mention in one of the post so that it will follow both the Is and LSP